# How do I grab a txt from the internet and enter into an array?

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to copy http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt into an array for hangman game. I have this so far..

```
url = new URL("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutor… );
urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.getInputStream());

inStream in = new InputStreamReader("dictionary.txt");
urlConn.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

String nextLine;
String[] secretwordbank;
secretwordbank = new String[80368];
```

secretwordbank is an array representing a dictionary of words. This may be too big of an array so I'm open for ideas to optimize it. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really just unsure how to convert a `BufferedReader` into an array (or other collection) of strings, based on line breaks? If so, I'd suggest using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
List<String> lines = CharStreams.readLines(reader);
```

(As an aside, I would suggest specifying an encoding when creating the `InputStreamReader` - otherwise it will use the platform default encoding. Ideally, you should use the content-type header from the response to determine the encoding... there are higher-level HTTP libraries which will do all of this for you, such as [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).)

Comment: It is my first time working with BufferedReader, so yes.  However, this is an assignment for my teacher.  If I use guava he won't necessarily have the library. Correct?

Comment: @user1093111: I don't know - you should ask your teacher whether using external libraries is acceptable. But I'd suggest using a `List<String>` rather than an array... look at `BufferedReader.readLine()` and think about how you'd put that in a loop...

Comment: So you'd use an array list because you don't have to know how big your array is- in this case [80368].

Comment: For the bufferReader.readLine(), I could use a while loop correct?

Comment: @user1093111: Correct on both counts, yes. Note that when `readLine()` returns null, that means you've reached the end of the data.

Comment: Ok. So my rest of my code was based on an array instead of and arraylist. I use 'code'String secretword = secretwordbank[r.nextInt(secretwordbank.length)];'code' Will this be effected?
As wel as-
'code'
char[] secretlettersarray = secretword.toCharArray();
 
String secretwordprompt = repeat("-", secretlettersarray.length );
char[] secretwordpromptarray = secretwordprompt.toCharArray();
'code'

Comment: @user1093111: I would change the rest of your code to work with collections instead of arrays, to be honest. They're generally more friendly to work with.

Comment: Thanks, You've helped alot just kinda working through everything. I'll work on changing everything.

Comment: So I don't look like a fool again, how do you do the html formating in comments? <code>, or 'code'

Answer (score 1):

Use this Java code to build your list of words:

```
URL url = new URL("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt");
URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = urlConn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String nextLine;
List<String> secretwordbank = new ArrayList<String>();

while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    secretwordbank.add(nextLine);
}
System.out.println("Secret Word List: " + secretwordbank);
```

**Edit:** If you're looking to have an `array of String` rather than a `List<String>`

```
String[] wordBankArr = secretwordbank.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println("Secret Word Array: " + Arrays.toString(wordBankArr));
```

Comment: Sweet, Thanks. String[] wordBankArr = secretwordbank.toArray(new String[0]); ----replaces--- List<String> secretwordbank = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to close streams in the end like this: `br.close();` and `in.close();`

Comment: Question, since I'm trying to use arrays, I'm using the edit. However, I don't understand what happens with 
swordBankArr = secretwordbank.toArray.  

secretwordbank never was intialized

Comment: `secretwordbank` was initialized at the time of declaration above i.e. `List<String> secretwordbank = new ArrayList<String>();` and it was populated in `while loop`

Comment: ok so then the the collection secretwordbank is then converted into an array that is wordbankarr. Do i need to make the wordbankarr an array of [80368] or is it already formatted with collection?

Comment: You don't need to make `wordBankArr` is any particular size since it is declared and initialized in one statement `String[] wordBankArr = secretwordbank.toArray(new String[0]);` which means that `wordBankArr` will have exactly same size as `secretwordbank.size()`.